# Points of intersection of vector with cone.

Tags: vectors, conic-sections, intersection-theory

I have a Vector $\vec A$ defined as : $(A_o+t*A_d)$

I also have a Cone with vertex (cone tip) ***V*** and axis direction $\vec D$, base radius ***R*** and height ***H***. The cone angle can be computed via $θ=2{tan^-}^1(R/H)$.

How can I find the 2 points of intersection between the vector and cone?

Here's a simple illustration:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get a handle on the problem, it makes sense to set the vertex of the cone to be the origin of co-ordinates. then the axis direction can be specified by a unit vector $\bar v$, and the test line is defined by a single real parameter $t$ as
$$
\bar r = \bar a + \bar b t
$$
a point on the cone is distinguished by the fact that its distance from the axis is a constant fraction of its distance from the vertex. let us just call this $\lambda$ - it is, as you say, determined by the dimensions of the cone.
so this condition may be expressed as:
$$
(\bar r \cdot \bar r)-(\bar r \cdot \bar v)^2 = \lambda^2 (\bar r \cdot \bar r) 
$$
substituting for $r$ will give you a quadratic equation in $t$, which may have $0,1$ or $2$ solutions

Comment: in your answer, is $r^2$ the base radius of the cone and $\vec r$ the test vector?

Comment: no, it's the magnitude of $r$. i've changed the text slightly to clarify this

Comment: and how do you define λ? Is it the distance of the point X to the axis or to the Vertex?

Comment: in terms of the notation in your question $\lambda = \cos \theta$